# Get properties from Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm failing at passing a property from a `<Route />`

Here is some code :

**./app.jsx** *(main app)*

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import App from './components/app'
import Home from './components/home'
import About from './components/about'

render((
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home} title="Home" />
            <Route path="about" component={About} title="About" />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

**./components/app.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './template/header'

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header title={this.props.title} />
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

**./components/template/header.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'

class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <span>{this.props.title}</span>
        )
    }
}

export default Header
```

When I click on my *home* route* I want my `Header` component to display `Home`.

When I click on my *about* route I want my `Header` component to display `About`.

At this point, my `Header` components displays nothing. `this.props.title` is `undefined` in my `App` component.
Looks like you can't pass an attribute from a `<Route />`

Is there a way to achieve this?

Or is there another way? For instance, can you *get something* **from** the children element (`this.props.children.title` or something like that) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the route injects a `routes` property with a list of the matching routes. The last route in the list has the props you specify. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obZzBa?editors=001

```
const routes = this.props.routes;
const lastRoute = routes[routes.length - 1];
const title = lastRoute.title;
```

I'd hesitate a little to use this, since `routes` is not documented in the [Injected Props](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/API.md#injected-props), so I don't know how reliable it is across version updates. A simpler option, though not as legible, would be to use `this.props.location.pathname` and maintain a lookup table for titles.

The best and most flexible option is probably the boilerplate-heavy one, where you define the template and then reuse it across components:

```
class Template extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header title={this.props.title} />
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class About extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Template title="About">
                Some Content
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```